# MATLAB Canny edge detection: Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached

Tags: matlab, recursion, numbers

i'm getting this error

> Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached

as I try to execute the function `edge(img,'canny')`.
Fun fact is that the function is called within a script which worked til now (and now it doesn't).

I tried to increase the maximum iteration number ( `set(0,'RecursionLimit,value)` ) but if I try values too low it appears the same error, if I try values too high the system crashes.

What can I do?

--Update--

I tried to executed the edge() function without specifying 'canny'... This way it works, but I absolutely need the canny edge method!!

--Update--

It also works with the 'sobel' method. Could the problem be on 'canny'?

--Update--

Solved! The problem was a function I created this morning named "gradient" which overriden the function "gradient" called by the Canny Edge detector method

Comment: What image do you use? It sounds like the algorithm is not converging, i.e. reaches its maximum number of iterations. This could mean your image is inappropriate. Please attach your image.

Comment: I'm using this http://www.filedropper.com/lenna512, but I already used that function in a script on the same image many times.. Until this morning I get this error and I don't know why: on a different pc it works!

Comment: This is a `n00b` question, but did you try restarting MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't convert your image to black and white properly. The values stored in your 512 by 512 matrix are on the scale of 0 to 255. To reduce it to the black and white scale used by the [edge()](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/edge.html) function simply divide by 255.

```
% Load data file
load('lenna512.mat')

% Scale to proper intensity range for the type double (0 to 1)
lenna512_bw = lenna512/255;

% Preview figure if it went alright
figure(1)
imshow(lenna512_bw);

% Detect the edges
edges_result = edge(lenna512_bw,'canny');

% Show result
figure(2)
imshow(result)
```

**Note** Intensity images of the type double have the range 0 to 1 while intensity images of type uint8 or uint16 have the range 0 to 255. So instead of using:

```
lenna512_bw = lenna512/255;
```

You could also use:

```
lenna512_bw = uint8(lenna512);
```

or

```
lenna512_bw = uint16(lenna512);
```

Converting the matrix to the type uint8 or uint16 while having the appropriate range for these types set to 0 to 255 as already available in your matrix.

More on imagetypes [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-175) and on numerical types [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/numeric-types.html)

Good luck!

The resulting images:

[image: Lenna 1]
[image: Lenna 2]

Comment: Sorry, I tried but it didn't worked and the same error occured! The problem isn't in the image or in its format (as I said before, it worked until this morning, and now doesn't, inexplicabily).

Comment: The problem might be in the rest of your code. MatLab's recursion limit may not be defined per function but on a global level. You could try to put the code part containing the edge() function in a different file. However, without seeing the rest of your code I cannot judge that.